# Use regex pattern matching to remove the two leading and trailing lines

Tags: java, regex

I have string looks like below, the string is joined by line-breaker. In this string, the the first 2 lines and last two lines are fixed, `public class FakeClass {/n public void fakeMethod() {/n`

```
    String sampleCode =
        String.format(
            createLines(7),
            "public class FakeClass {\n",
            "  public void fakeMethod() {\n",
            "    int a = 5;\n",
            "    int b = 6;\n",
            "    a = b;\n",
            "  }\n",
            "}\n");
        );

  private static String createLines(int numLines) {
    return new String(new char[numLines]).replace("\0", "%s");
  }
```

I want to get rid of two leading and two trailing lines. I can simply use substring

```
String result = sampleCode.substring(53, sampleCode.length() - 5)
```

The output is:

```
assertEqual(result, String.format(
       createLine(3),
       "    int a = 5;\n",
       "    int b = 6;\n",
       "    a = b;\n",
       ));
```

I wonder if we could Use regex pattern matching to remove the two leading and trailing lines.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output

Comment: Split by `\n` to get an array of individual lines and then do a sublist by discarding first 2 elements

Comment: just add expected output.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, but I am looking for a way use regex. split by `\n` take another space.

Comment: What is `createLines(7)` or `createLines(3)` ?

Comment: @anubhava just add function, sorry my bad.

Comment: You can try: `String code = sampleCode.replaceAll("^([^\n]*\\n){2}|([^\n]*\\n){2}$", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to remove first 2 and last 2 lines:

```
String code = sampleCode.replaceAll("^([^\n]*\n){2}|([^\n]*\n){2}$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNaWV1/1)

- `^([^\n]*\n){2}` matches first 2 lines of string
- `([^\n]*\n){2}$` matches last 2 lines of string

Answer (score 0):

need to use **java.util.regex.Pattern** to active multiline search :

```
String sampleCode
        = String.format(
                createLines(7),
                "public class FakeClass {\n",
                "  public void fakeMethod() {\n",
                "    int a = 5;\n",
                "    int b = 6;\n",
                "    a = b;\n",
                "  }\n",
                "}\n");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=.*[{}])(.*)",Pattern.MULTILINE);
sampleCode = pattern.matcher(sampleCode).replaceAll("");
pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+)$",Pattern.MULTILINE);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(sampleCode).replaceAll("\"$1\\\\n\""));
```

output :

```
"    int a = 5;\n"
"    int b = 6;\n"
"    a = b;\n"
```

you can use **trim()** method to delete \n in each deleted line

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The expected result should maintain the indent and line break.

Comment: I also tried ```String result = sampleCode.replace("public class FakeClass {\n", "")
        .replace("  public void fakeMethod() {\n", "")``` to remove  the first trailing lines. But I didn't work out the last two lines something like "  }\\r?\\n}$".

Comment: i change it and it work as expected , in the first regex it remove the first two and the last two line in the second bring back `" \n"`